# Is it possible to lanch the workflow initiation form in modal window?

Tags: dialog-framework, workflow

I want to have the initiation form inside a modal popup. Here's what I've figured out so far:

To open the form insisde a modal dialog, I've included this inside the "Navigatate to Url" in the custom action.

```
javascript:function openDialog() {  
    var options = { 
    url: "http://<server>/srd/Workflows/wf_lobEnd/wf_lobEnd.aspx",
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: "User Story"
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
openDialog();
```

This works fine. Question is how to modify the wf_lobend.aspx form so that the popup closes, and the initiation form get submitted.

This is the javascript that gets generated for me behind the ok buttun of the initiation form:

```
            <input type="button" value="Start" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__insert;__commit;__redirectsource;__redirectToList={',ddwrt:EcmaScriptEncode($ListName),'};'))}" />
```

That is a bit cryptic to me, so I'm not sure what to replace. I know that I must use something like this to get the dialog closed, but that does not seem to submit the form:

```
onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, 'Ok clicked'); return false;"
```

Question is: How to close the dialog and still post the data?

(or maybe I've take the complete wrong approach, in case please let me know)

Regards

Larsi

Larsi

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar, starting a workflow from a modal dialog. The form that i used does not have any fields, but it still posts back and starts the workflow.

http://djeeg.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-designer-custom-action-in.html

The code i used to open the dialog is this

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    url:"{SiteUrl}/_layouts/Com.CodePlex.SPC3/StartWorkflow.aspx?List={ListId}&ItemID={SelectedItemId}&Workflow=WorkflowName",
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) 
    }
})
```

Try adding the dialogReturnValueCallback property to the open dialog options. I did not have to modify any of the automatically generated dialog button javascript.

**EDIT**

Though looking at the page source i did have to do something extra to get it to redirect

http://spc3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55971#985217

```
if (Request["IsDlg"] == "1") {
    Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.End();
} else {
    SPUtility.Redirect(list.DefaultViewUrl, SPRedirectFlags.UseSource, Context);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback. But I still don't understand how to get the data posted? If I use the default implementation, I get a error saying "The data source control failed to execute the insert command". The script the gets exceuted is the same: javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$InitiationForm$ctl01','__insert;__commit;__redirectsource;__redirectToList={{2ff87457-1767-4402-b04f-a28d841b40be}};') Any idea what causing this?

Comment: In your form wf_lobEnd.aspx, how are you creating the Save button? My forms looks like this <input type="submit" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonOk" value="Ok" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ButtonOk">

Comment: Save button is created with xslt using this magic code: <input type="button" value="Start" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__insert;__commit;__redirectsource;__redirectToList={',ddwrt:EcmaScriptEncode($ListName),'};'))}" />

Comment: Did you create the page wf_lobEnd.aspx or was it generated from something? What webparts are on it? Or is it an InfoPath form?

Comment: It's generated from SD Sharepoint WF designer. It has a DataFormWebPart on it.

Comment: are you using foundation, standard or enterprise?